# best way to link file to answer?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to answer a question where part of the solution involves apply a patch file. Obviously, having the exact patch file is important to that working, but it's too many characters to include as part of the answer, and generating it the first time around was a difficult/black magic process that I'm not sure I could easily explain in an answer.

Is there a recommended way to include things like this in an answer? Should I infer from this problem that this isn't a good way to answer the question?

My original thought would be to link to something like GitHub, but my employer frowns upon code upload sites (except this one) for obvious reasons.

## EDIT

Seems like the consensus is 'if you have to do this, it's not going to be a good answer'.

Comment: What are the obvious reasons?  Also; without seeing the question, there's no way to know why your answer would be so long that it couldn't be contained in the answer.

Comment: I don't think we will get a file upload system [Please add a system to allow file uploads attached to questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/please-add-a-system-to-allow-file-uploads-attached-to-questions-and-answers) is [tag:status-declined].  That said an answer should not have any external links unless they are the to augment the answer.  The question should be answered with the text of the answer alone otherwise it is not an answer.

Comment: Smells like an off topic question.

Comment: Let's start with the low-hanging fruit:  Stack Overflow isn't a code uploading site.  Let your employer know that.  The sooner they know, the better off *everyone* working beneath them is.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker they're worried people are going to give away their intellectual property either purposefully or inadvertently, and they don't have the technical skills or inclination to create a more logical system than 'don't do it'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each and every person has their own style of teaching, but let's assume you were in the opposite position.  Someone has a solution for you, and while *some* of it is explained, they provide you a magical patch file that should "just work" for your case.

Except...it doesn't.  No code is truly going to be "one size fits all".

I won't argue that the patch file may help the OP out of their particular jam, but that's not the only reason we're here.  We're creating answers to transcend the OP's use case, and patch files don't scale well.

It would be my preference if you didn't provide patch files (especially linked to external sites, since they could go dark while Stack Overflow is up), but if you ***really*** want to, you could just paste it in a code block.  Bear in mind, you may get flak for it being "unreadable".

Comment: Does this handle the "_but it's too many characters to include as part of the answer_" consideration?

Comment: @ryanyuyu:  So...the patch file would take up more characters than is allotted?   Isn't that on the order of 30K?  If I wrote a patch file that, it's tantamount to doing their work for them, and I'm pretty sure I'd want my fair share of the profits.

Comment: No idea, but that's how I interpreted the OP's question.  It could just be a miscommunication though.

Comment: @Makoto maybe I'm too altruistic :P If it makes more sense, I was thinking about a Q&A style question, so I would have been doing my own work. That said I wasn't sure it was really appropriate which is why I asked on meta in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a bad idea. Applying binary patch from random post on internet - nothing ever can wrong with that :).

SO is not authoritative source of any library/system - either link to original source *or* provide description how to obtain one.

Comment: maybe, maybe not a bad idea. patch files are plain text, and you can read them if you care to see what they're doing. I certainly do, and I've gained insight about the patched file from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is **not** a code upload site. It is a site to ask questions and to answer them, generally in the form of a complete solution which may or may not involve code.

If applying a patch is part of a solution, then how to obtain/create that patch most definitely is part of the answer; the answer is incomplete and useless without those detailed steps. To me this meta question is pretty much the poster example of what SO is about: you **do** make the incredible effort to write how to create that patch, it is exactly the fact that you can find the black magic incantation on SO that makes SO so great and why people keep coming back.

Teach how to fish, don't just give the fish.

Comment: I get your point that there's a difference between a site whose primary purpose is as a code repository, and a site where you may copy/paste snippets of code, but I don't think it's relevant to the question really and regardless right or wrong my employer doesn't see a distinction

Comment: I understand that you can't post it due to company privacy rules - then unfortunately you are not the one to provide the answer :(